# moment timezone returns bad value for unit test

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So my project is using moment timezone. And it works perfectly everywhere its used except in a unit test. And I can't figure out why.

I'm calling

```
moment(new Date(date)).tz(timezone).format(mask);
```

where the date, mask, and timezone are as follows:

```
date     = "2016-11-11T19:34:56.601Z"
mask     = "mm-dd-yyyy"
timezone = "America/New_York"
```

The result I get is: `34-Fr-yyyy`

In another call, the following occurs:

```
date     = "2016-12-13T21:57:53.336Z"
mask     = "mm-dd-yyyy"
timezone = "America/New_York"
```

and the result is `57-Tu-yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong date format, the correct is `MM-DD-YYYY`.

```js
var date     = "2016-12-13T21:57:53.336Z";
var mask     = "mm-dd-yyyy";
var timezone = "America/New_York";

var dateStr = moment(date).tz(timezone).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
console.log(dateStr);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format